# Passing parameters to UserControl constructor in c# 2.0

Tags: user-controls, c#-2.0

Is there a way to pass the parameters to the LoadControl function when loading the user control dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that uses reflection [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202094005/http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2006/03/23/73096.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is create a descendant of the UserControl class, add a default constructor and another constructor that takes your parameters. The parameterless constructor is necessary for designer support.

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl() : base()
    {
       // do initialization stuff...
    }

    public MyControl(int parameter) : this()
    {
       // do additional stuff with parameter
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I know how to write a constructor:) I was more referring to the dynamic User Control creation with LoadControl function. How do I pass a parameter to the constructor to this function. Sorry, if I weren't clear.

Comment: I thought the problem was with the Visual Studio designer not displaying the user control (which may be the case when you do not provide a parameterless constructor)...